# Why does .bash_history take more than one go to erase?

Tags: bash, command-history

The question says it all, really.

If I delete the ~/.bash_history file and close my (only) shell, then reopen it, often there are still a few commands left.

Deleting it twice usually does the job of completely erasing it. I might be wrong but I think I've even done it a third time before.

This happens the same even if I do 'echo > ~/.bash_history' to replace it with a carriage return. It's also similar on Ubuntu and Fedora.

What gives? Is it being cached somewhere?

Comment: When you exit the current shell session, the history of it is written to the history file.

Comment: When you exit bash, it writes the local history cacheto the .bash_history file. To clean the history, enter `history -c`

Comment: Even if I do 'history -c' it still saves the last few commands.